# Reverse Engineering URL Algorithm

Tags: java, android, url, reverse-engineering

I have a URL I'm attempting to obtain data from - when doing a complete search which returns all results it is possible to use:

```
http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=&fname=
```

however each individual has their own page which can be referenced as follows:

```
http://sheriff.org/apps/arrest/details.cfm?id=7133e45d-3115-4ec8-bd0b-35cb9e193e50&key=CEFC904002B745E5265D6A76402610A2&page=1&lname=&fname=
```

...which is composed of an ID and a KEY.

```
ID = 7133e45d-3115-4ec8-bd0b-35cb9e193e50

KEY = CEFC904002B745E5265D6A76402610A2
```

How can I determine how this ID can be generated?

I presume it is based upon some of the individual's details (possibly their arrest number: 501207593 or the arrest number plus some other data)

I simply need a method of reverse engineering this number so I can use it in my android application.

Comment: I just got a downvote - why? Isn't this a perfectly reasonable question?

Comment: @Selvin: No, you missed the point. He wants to know the magic algo that generates the ID and Key. That is quite impossible to know.

Comment: The ID is a GUID somehow generated for each person arrested. It will not be possible for you to get this number without it being exposed to you (i.e. in a screen scrape). If they don't expose an API to you there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Looks like a standard GUID and not at all built from data on the person...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about violating the terms and conditions of a 3rd party service.

Comment: I don't think I'm violating the terms and conditions of the site... all information is considered public records:

"This information is made available to the public and law enforcement in the interest of public safety. "


Is shown at the bottom of the screen. If I'm doing something wrong/illegal I'll be happy to stop now - but I'm pretty sure what I'm doing is legal and legit. : )

Comment: @user2856134  You may well be right, although software licenses which permit reverse engineering are rare.  I suggest that you contact them.  If it is indeed legal and legit and are public record, then they should assist you.  Good luck.

Comment: So... proceeding without reverse engineering this algorithm (and simply using the data at face value) would seem to be ok I would think. Would you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I determine how this ID can be generated?

This type of id is known as [UUID (Universally Unique Identifier).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). A UUID is a 16-octet (128-bit) number. In its canonical form, a UUID is represented by 32 hexadecimal digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens). The canonical representation, `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Learn about [java UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the code of the server, or know anybody that has access to the code, it is impossible to tell how the server generates these numbers. That can be either totally random or based on user details or a mix of both.

However, as @OnResolve pointed out. The ID seems to be formatted as a GUID (Global Unique Identifier). But this doesn't tell anything about how they are generated.